# how to run ajax while the application is on background mode?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, background-mode

I have a problem on sending ajax while the application is on background mode! 
in fact my application is like a taxi app and I want to send user location and sending it to server, but when the application is on background it does not work. I use the background-mode plugin for that.
could anyone please help me what is the solution?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use web worker to run process in the background. This is the document [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)